# How to serialize output from schemacrawler to JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, schemacrawler

I would like to upgrade schemacrawler that I use from version 11.01.01 to version 16.20.5. I've already managed to adapt most of the code, but there is this one last thing I can't figure out.

The code using schemacrawler 11.01.01 created a JSON output this way:

```
OutputOptions outputOptions = new OutputOptions(TextOutputFormat.json.getFormat(), file);
```

Both `OutputOptions` and `TextOutputFormat` were in `schemacrawler.tools.options` package.

How to implement this functionality in the new version? Could you please help me?

I found the information that writing output to JSON should be possible and how to do it using the command line. But I need an example of how to do it in **Java**. I see that there is Jackson, but I still don't know how to use it with schemacrawler.

Answer (score 0):

Anna,

You need to use the `serialize` command with [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/), as well as set the output format to JSON. There are now builders to build the options. Since you are jumping ahead by a few major versions of [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/), I have created a working example for you at https://github.com/sualeh/sc-example Please use this as a starting point for your code.

Sualeh Fatehi
[SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and creating an example. I am sorry to bother you again, but I am afraid the usage of the current version of SchemaCrawler is still not clear for me. I should mention that my database types are DB2 and MSSQL. In version 11.01.01 the command that I execute is "details". When I use this command now, I get the exception: schemacrawler.schemacrawler.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Output format <json> not supported for command <details>. When I use "serialize" then I get: schemacrawler.schemacrawler.exceptions.ExecutionRuntimeException: Unknown command <serialize>.

Comment: Anna, the example above is a working example using the latest ScheamCrawler version, v16.20.6. Please use that as a starting point. Did you get the example working?

If you are getting an unknown command error, check your classpath, and make sure it is the same as in the example.

Comment: Yes, I get the example and my code working. I had in fact a mistake in classpath, thank you for pointing that out. Now I am able to use the 'serialize' command, but in the older version I used the command 'details', which causes an exception in the new version: schemacrawler.schemacrawler.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Output format <json> not supported for command <details>. Is there a way for me to get an output identical as before or do I have to adjust my code to the new output?

Comment: Anna, the JSON output in previous versions was hand-crafted, but in this version, the JSON is generated using Jackson. Sorry, there is no way to get the old format in the new version.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help! Everything is now clear to me.